# How to force Mac screen resolution?

Tags: display, hdmi, resolution

Whenever I connect my Mac FireWire-to-HDMI to a large-screen TV, the resolution on my MacBook Air 11″ becomes larger and more content fits on the screen. In other words, everything scales *down* and it looks great. I'd like this resolution to be forced at all times. This option is only available when the MacBook Air is output to a larger HDMI screen.

Here is what the settings panel looks like with the desired resolution:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The setting you wish to adjust is the ***built-in display*** correct?  Your screenshot is for the external.

To change the built-in display on a retina screen running Yosemite:

- Unplug your HDMI (as in normal use)
- Go the the **Display preferences** ( > **System Preferences**)
- Set the display to **Scaled** and **More Space**.

Play a bit with it to get the look you desire.  Note: this may affect performance.

[image: Display pref]

When connected:
[image: Settings]

Comment: I did as you said. I do not see that option.

[Preview](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1333628/SHARED/my-mac-resolution.png)

Comment: Again, that is your EXTERNAL display.  You should have another for the Air itself.

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Where is the internal display option?

Comment: Usually on the Mac screen. It may be hidden beneath the other.

Comment: Found it. That preference screen also doesn't show a scale feature like yours did. Tell me why that is?

[Preview](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1333628/SHARED/my-mac-dont-show-scale.png)

Comment: The scale is for Retina displays.  But you can set yours to the highest res to get the effect you want all the same.  Hope this worked for you! Cheers

Comment: I'm already on the highest res.