# Any way to force Macbook to display resolution above its native resolution?

Tags: display, resolution

This seems to be a duplicate of [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/200082/how-to-force-mac-screen-resolution).  I'm not sure if I should reply to that question to "bump" it to the top, or if it is acceptable to "repost" a similar question if the previous question has not been satisfactorily answered after more than 5 years.

Anyway, in the linked question above, the commenter who tried to help seems to keep misunderstanding the original asker.  I, like the original asker, am curious as to whether it is possible to force my BUILT-IN Macbook display to run at a resolution HIGHER than its native resolution.

Now, I know that you can't create more pixels out of thin air, but as in the original question, I've seen my 1366x768 MacBook Air display *mirroring* a connected 4k external display, and it looks great and *perfectly usable* (even if the text is a bit blurry, obviously).

Is there a way to *force* my MacBook Air to run as a "4k" device (or anything above the native resolution) when it is *not* connected to an external 4k device?  I've seen that the computer *can do it*, so how can I *make it* do it *on demand*?

Comment: I think the answer is going to be the same - yes if it's a retina screen, no if it's not. We'd need to know the precise Mac model to know for sure.

Comment: Have a look at **Display Menu** in the **App Store**.

Comment: It's a MacBook Air 2014 model.  I've seen the screen display a 4k image (obviously it's scaled and not true 4k, but it was mirroring the same layout and screen real estate that I saw on my 4k external screen).  I tried **Display Menu** - even paid for the **Pro** version - and it didn't unlock any additional screen resolution options.  I highly doubt anything from the App Store would be able to do what needs to be done.  I'd imagine it would need something that operates on a "lower level".